# Given revenue and product price how can I optimize the price taking into account the time of year?

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm looking at a data set with 36 data points and three columns price, revenue and month/year.

I'd like to know how to fit a model to this data that takes into account the time of year and find the best price given a time of year.

My preliminary searches brought me to multiple-regression but I am still not sure if that is the correct approach. My two independent variables would be the month and the price... however, knowing the dataset origin, I suspect there is some correlation between price and month.

I am looking for a resource where I can learn about this so any explanation or reference would really help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Start with exploratory analysis, e.g. scatter plots of units sold by prices, color coded with time of year. Look up what others are doing to model price elasticity of demand. You could try fitting simple models such as 
$$R_t/P_t=\beta_0+\beta P_t + I^W_t+ I^S_t+ I^F_t+\varepsilon_t$$
where $R_t,P_t$ - revenue and price, $I^x_t$ - winder, spring and fall dummies with summer as a base. You expect that $\beta<0$.

This is very primitive. The reality's that demand depends on prices of other goods, such as substitutes and complements; it can be time varying etc. There's also inflation etc. There are a lot of complications